# Installation of Portlet feature fails on Websphere Liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty

I followed the [instructions](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/7e2e8015-bf72-43b6-bacd-36565b67febc/entry/Using_WebSphere_Application_Server_for_Liberty_profile_to_deploy_and_run_Portlets?lang=en)
to install the portlet feature on my local websphere liberty server.

But when I try to install the portlet feature, I get an error, that this feature is not found:

```
D:\Java\websphere-liberty\bin>installUtility install portlet-2.0
Die Verbindungen zu den konfigurierten Repositorys werden hergestellt...
Dieser Prozess kann mehrere Minuten dauern.

Es wurden Verbindungen zu allen konfigurierten Repositorys hergestellt.

Assets werden für die Installation vorbereitet. Die Ausführung dieses Prozesses kann mehrere Minuten dauern.
CWWKF1259E: Die folgenden Assets können nicht abgerufen werden: portlet-2.0. Stellen Sie sicher, dass die angegebenen Assets gültig sind. Führen Sie den installUtility-Befehl find aus, um die IDs der gültigen
Assets zu ermitteln.
```

Is the feature no longer supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

portlet-2.0 is always an unsupported feature under the IBM international License Agreement for Non- Warranted Programs. It has been removed and no longer available from WASDev downloads (https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads).